# How to adjust a response variable by extracting random effects?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model

I am working on dataset where I need to eliminate the random effects from the input response variable. For this, I am first extracting the random effects by using `extract_random_effects()` function from [mixedup](https://github.com/m-clark/mixedup) package.

After this point, I am not sure how to use the values of effects to adjust my response variable. For example, in the following example, I am looking for a way to adjust ‘Reaction’ variable by taking eliminating the random effect of ‘Subject’. How should I use the values given by extract_random_effects() to adjust ‘Reaction’ variable?

```
library(lme4)
library(glmmTMB)
library(mixedup)

data(sleepstudy)

tmb_model <- glmmTMB(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), 
                data = sleepstudy)
extract_random_effects(tmb_model)

dput(extract_random_effects(tmb_model))

structure(list(group_var = c("Subject", "Subject", "Subject", 
"Subject", "Subject", "Subject", "Subject", "Subject", "Subject", 
"Subject", "Subject", "Subject", "Subject", "Subject", "Subject", 
"Subject", "Subject", "Subject"), effect = c("Intercept", 
   "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", "Intercept", 
"Intercept"), group = structure(c(17L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 11L, 
14L, 8L, 3L, 18L, 4L, 13L, 5L, 16L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 15L), 
   .Label = c("309", 
"310", "335", "349", "351", "370", "371", "334", "330", "369", 
"332", "331", "350", "333", "372", "352", "308", "337"), 
   class = "factor"), 
    value = c(40.635, -77.566, -62.879, 4.39, 10.179, 8.191, 
    16.44, -2.986, -45.117, 71.92, -21.119, 14.06, -7.834, 36.246, 
    7.011, -6.34, -3.282, 18.05), se = c(12.535, 12.651, 12.596, 
    12.491, 12.493, 12.492, 12.498, 12.491, 12.545, 12.628, 
    12.503, 
    12.496, 12.492, 12.526, 12.492, 12.492, 12.491, 12.499), 
    lower_2.5 = c(16.067, -102.361, -87.567, -20.092, -14.308, 
    -16.294, -8.055, -27.468, -69.705, 47.168, -45.624, -10.432, 
    -32.318, 11.696, -17.473, -30.823, -27.764, -6.449), 
     upper_97.5 = c(65.203, 
    -52.771, -38.191, 28.873, 34.666, 32.676, 40.936, 21.496, 
    -20.529, 96.671, 3.386, 38.552, 16.651, 60.796, 31.495, 
       18.144, 
    21.2, 42.548)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: By eliminating the random effects, do you want to the adjusted response to be equal to the fixed component or the fixed component + the residual?

Comment: Hi, in my actual dataset, my response and predictor are measured in two different years. While I can model the effect of year on my response variable by adding year as the random effect, however I am not sure how do I eliminate the effect of year on my fixed variable which was measured in a different year than the response variable. That's why my objective is to eliminate the effect of year from my predictor variable prior to running the model.

Comment: You've omitted important details from the question. It's also unclear why you need to eliminate the random effects from the input response variable. Consider writing a new question where you describe your actual dataset, ideally with representative data, the variables and the model you want to fit.